# After effects project ask for Red Giant Particular even if is installed

Tags: adobe, effects, after-effects, adobe-premiere

So I have on D installed After Effects and on C partition I installed Red Giant but how I link them so AE will not ask me again about the particular effect?

Red Giant install libraries to Adobe or Adobe tries to search for libraries?If Adobe search for libraries it should be a place where to edit  the link from where it takes  the data.

Comment: Maybe you should write to the Read Giant support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved but I'm not sure if is 100% solved.

Go to C:\Adobe and from the Support Files And Common folders you copy the content to your new location and those should do the link